# Parameterizing a kdb q script

Tags: kdb, parameterization

I'm writing a kdb/q script which will somehow have to prompt for user input and then add that input into several otherwise-preformatted queries. Suggestions on how to prompt/accept the input and parameterize the queries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accept user input using `read0 0`, which waits will catch all a user types until they hit enter. The input will then be returned as a string. You can either type this into an active q session or wrap it up in a function like this:

```
q)f:{a:read0 0;show a}
q)f[]
12
"12"
```

In this case I have typed `12` which is returned as the string `"12"`.

As for parameterising queries this can be done through strings, but this is not very q so to speak. You would be better to cast the inputs to another type and use functional form or even standard selects, for example:

```
q)tab:([]a:1 2 3 4)
q){input:"J"$read0 0;select from tab where a=input}[]
4
a
-
4
```

You can read more about [functional form](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/funsql/) on the Kx wiki.

Answer (score 4):

You can pass the input as command-line arguments too, using [`.z.x`](https://code.kx.com/wiki/Reference/dotzdotx) & `.Q.opt` :

```
$ q -item cam
q)p:.Q.opt .z.x
q)p`item
item| "cam"

q)select from tab where items=first `$p`item
items sales prices
------------------
cam   0     15
```

Answer (score 2):

Checkout [`read0`](https://code.kx.com/wiki/Reference/read0) to read the inputs from console.

```
q)rl:{1">> "; value "select from tab where items=`",read0 0}
q)rl`
>> cam
items sales prices
------------------
cam   0     15
```

Answer (score 2):

For user input, you can use `read0` on file handle `0` - standard input. User prompt would be printed to standard output (file descriptor `1`) like this:

```
1 "Please give me some input: ";
input: read0 0;
```

For query parametrization, you can go either with string concatenation of functional query form as described [here (code.kx.com)](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/funsql/)